How do I resolve a FieldError(Cannot resolve keyword '...' into field.) in Django?
I am trying to have clients search for service providers in my search.html stored in the database that only belong to a specific category of services.
This is the snippet from the template handling the search:
<form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}">
  <select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="">Select a category</option>
    {% for category_key, category_name in service_categories %}
    <option value="{{ category_key }}">{{ category_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

This is the current logic in the views.py for the search template.
def search(request):
    # Capture search criteria from request parameters
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    start_time = request.GET.get('start_time')
    end_time = request.GET.get('end_time')

    # Initialize search results
    search_results = None

    if category or (start_time and end_time):
        # Filter providers based on category and availability
        query = ServiceProvider.objects.all()
        if category:
            query = query.filter(services__category=category)
        if start_time and end_time:
            try:
                start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
                end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
                query = query.filter(
                    availabilities__start_time__lte=end_time,
                    availabilities__end_time__gte=start_time
                )
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing availability: {e}")
        search_results = query.distinct()

    # Fetch Popular or Featured Providers (modify based on your logic)
    popular_providers = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(is_featured=True)[:3]

    service_categories = Service.service_categories

    context = {
        'search_results': search_results,
        'popular_providers': popular_providers,
        'service_categories': service_categories
    }

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)

These are the related models for ServiceProvider and Service:
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service_provider')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    average_rating = models.FloatField(default=0.0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Provider name')
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)  # Optional field for service provider image URL
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)  # Optional field for service provider description
    offers = models.TextField(blank=True)  # Field to store offered services (comma-separated or JSON format)
    pricing = models.TextField(blank=True)  # Field to store pricing information (text or JSON format)
    availability_description = models.TextField(blank=True)  # Text field for general availability info (e.g., "Weekdays 9am-5pm")
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Service(models.Model):
    service_categories = [
        ('Dance', 'Dance'),
        ('Music', 'Music'),
        ('MC', 'Master of Ceremonies'),
        # Add more categories as needed
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='services')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=service_categories)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} by {self.provider.user.username}"

So the error came from this particular line query = query.filter(category__services=category) in the views.py. I decided to post the full code of the view function for context.
I was expecting the code to return a list of service providers under a particular category, for example, 'Dance' but instead raised this error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'services' into field. Choices are: availabilities, availability_description, average_rating, description, id, image_url, is_featured, location, name, offers, pricing, user, user_id
I have a feeling the issue could be something small but I've personally failed to figure it out.
PS: Apologies if I've provided a lot of unnecessary code, it's my first time posting a question here. Also, if there is any more explanation required, I can provide it.

you bind Service to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL with foreign key.
you bind ServiceProvider to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL with foreign key.
Direct in you code the query should be like:
query = ServiceProvider.objects.filter(user__services__category=category)


thank you for replying. I have made those changes but I'm getting this error:
harmoniconnect.CustomUser: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'harmoniconnect.ServiceProvider.services', but it does not have a foreign key to 'ServiceProvider' or 'Service'.
harmoniconnect.Service.provider:(fields.E302) Reverse accessor 'ServiceProvider.services' for 'harmoniconnect.Service.provider' clashes with field name 'harmoniconnect.ServiceProvider.services'.
I tried changing the new field name but I think it's not the one I'm supposed to change, could you clarify that?

sorry, i did an error. you have two chained foreign. M2M not works. I delete it from answer.

The initial error(FieldError) is being raised again when I change it to what you've edited in your answer.

you are not provided enouth code: where is the field availabilities ? I load code of your model on  new django project, and ServiceProvider.filter(user__services__category=category) works!

I didn't think the availability filter would affect the initial filter based on service category. Filtering based on availability was meant to be done after receiving providers for service.
But here is code for the Availability model:
`class Availability(models.Model):
provider = models.ForeignKey(ServiceProvider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='availabilities')
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
def __str__(self):
    return f"Available from {self.start_time} to {self.end_time} for {self.provider.user.username}"`


allan, once more time: i copy your code in new django project, i did migrations, i apply filter as i say and i dont get any error in  ServiceProvider.filter(user__services__category=category). If you got an error, it should be other error or you dont apply my advice.

Apologies Maxim, I had appended the user bit but not changed the filter reference. On applying your suggested change, I am now getting this error:
type object 'ServiceProvider' has no attribute 'filter'

sorry for that: ServiceProvider.objects.filter

Yes, that worked but I found an easier workaround for the whole category filtering.
I decided to filter the Service objects and then get the corresponding ServiceProvider objects and it did the trick.
